# Matrix power and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to compute the power of the matrix A using multiplications.
I am having problems with the ArrayPower function.  It does not function as i think it should.The MultiArray function however seems to work fine. Can anyone help me ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int**  MultiArray(int a[2][2],int b[2][2]);
int**  ArrayPower(int a[2][2],int e);


int main(void)
{
    int fa[2][2];
    fa[0][0]=0;
    fa[0][1]=1;
    fa[1][0]=1;
    fa[1][1]=1;

    int **multifa=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        multifa[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    }

    multifa=ArrayPower(fa,2);

   printf("%d %d\n",multifa[0][0],multifa[0][1]);
   printf("%d %d\n",multifa[1][0],multifa[1][1]);

    return 0;

}

int**  MultiArray(int a[2][2], int b[2][2]) {

    //multi a *b
    //memory allocation
    int i,rows=2,cols=2;
    int **c=malloc(rows*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        c[i]=malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
    }


    c[0][0]=a[0][0]*b[0][0]+a[0][1]*b[1][0];
    c[0][1]=a[0][0]*b[0][1]+a[0][1]*b[1][1];

    c[1][0]=a[1][0]*b[0][0]+a[1][1]*b[1][0];
    c[1][1]=a[1][0]*b[0][1]+a[1][1]*b[1][1];


    return c;

}

int** ArrayPower(int a[2][2],int e) {


    //memory allocation
    int i,rows=2,cols=2;
    int **c=malloc(rows*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        c[i]=malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
    }

  c[0][0]=a[0][0];
  c[0][1]=a[0][1];
  c[1][0]=a[1][0];
  c[1][1]=a[1][1];

   for (i=1;i<e;i++) {
       c=MultiArray(a,c);
   }
   return c;

}
```

Comment: why are you allocating memory for `multifa`? the way you are doing it, you are loosing the reference to the allocated memory after the call to ArrayPower() and will leak the memory.

Comment: You 're right! It is not necessary. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MultiArray` is declared as taking a second parameter of type `int [2][2]`, but it is called with an argument of `c`, which as type `int **`. These are not compatible types.

In a parameter, the type `int [2][2]` is automatically converted to a pointer to an array of two `int`, the type `int (*)[2]`. This is a pointer to a place where there are two `int` objects (and, because we know it is the first element of an array of two arrays of two `int` objects, we know there are two more `int` objects beyond the first two).

The definition of `c` with `int **c` means that `c` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. A pointer to a pointer and a pointer to an array are different and are not compatible.

One way to fix this is to define `c` with `int (*c)[2] = malloc(2 * sizeof *c);`. It is then unnecessary to have the loop after the definition that allocates more space; the single allocation allocates the entire array.

The return type of `MultiArray` should be changed similarly, as well as the code within it and elsewhere in the program. Alternatively, the second parameter of `MultiArray` can be changed from `int b[2][2]` to `int **b`. (This latter is an easier edit but produces an inferior program, since it uses more pointers and allocations than necessary.)

You should always compile your code with warnings enabled. That would have alerted you to the incorrect call.